# Como criar uma div clicável?

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

Tenho uma div no meu site e quero torná-la clicável por meio do Javascript. Como faço isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Explique melhor o que precisa.... Vc quer executar algo clicando na Div, ou quer deixar a div marcada quando clicar nela. O que exatamente vc precisa. Edite a sua pergunta com o que já tiver de código.

Comment: De acordo com as suas tags, com um pouco de pesquisa deveria conseguir fazer o que pretende hehehe

Comment: Eu tenho uma div simples apenas. Gostaria de torná-la clicável e executar a função que eu desejar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de "criar" uma div clicável seria:

```css
#clicavel{
cursor: pointer;
}

#clicavel:hover{
color: red;
}

#clicavel:active{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script>
function executaAcao(){
alert("Eu vou para o Google");
window.location = "http://google.com";
}
</script>
<div id="clicavel" onclick="executaAcao()">CLIQUE AQUI</div>
```

Usamos o método `onclick` para atribuir uma função javascript ao elemento html e o atributos `:hover` e `:active` para personalizar o style do elemento conforme as ações do rato.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myDiv">
   Click me
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function() {
   alert('Clicked!');
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function res(){
  alert("Vc devia pesquisar mais")
}
```

```css
div{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="res()">
Click aqui
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, desde adicionar `onclick` na própria *tag* como criar eventos:

```js
// função
function f(){
   console.log("div clicada!");
}

// EventListener
document.querySelector("#minhadiv1").addEventListener("click", f);

// onclick
document.querySelector("#minhadiv3").onclick = f;
```

```css
#minhadiv1,
#minhadiv2,
#minhadiv3{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="minhadiv1">Clique-me</div>
<br />
<div id="minhadiv2" onclick="f()">Clique-me</div>
<br />
<div id="minhadiv3">Clique-me</div>
```

Pode adicionar o estilo `pointer` com CSS para alterar o cursor do mouse (vide código acima).